# How to show state functions are perfect differentials, or vice-versa?

Tags: thermodynamics

Suppose a variable $z$ is a function of two independent variables $x$ and $y$.

Now, if z can be expressed in its total differential form as
$$dz=Mdx+Ndy$$

Then show that $z$ is a state function iff
$$\Big(\dfrac{\partial M}{\partial y}\Big)_x=\Big(\dfrac{\partial N}{\partial x}\Big)_y$$

Comment: Why not ask it on maths site?

Comment: This is a standard integrability condition, it just says the form $\mathrm{d}z$ is closed, meaning it is locally exact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If z is a function of x and y, then:$$dz=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}dy$$So, $M=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $N=\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$.  Since the order of taking partial derivatives is immaterial,$$\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x \partial y}=\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$$

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the derivative of $dz$.

$$\begin{align} d(dz) &= \partial_yM\;dy\wedge dx + \partial_xN\;dx\wedge dy \\
&= \left(\partial_xN - \partial_yM\right)\;dx\wedge dy \end{align}$$

It is zero iff. the condition $(\cdots)=0$ holds, meaning $dz$ is a *closed 1-form*.

On a simply connected domain - that is one where every loop is contractible to a point - [Poincarés Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms#Poincar.C3.A9_lemma) asserts, that the form is also exact. Or in other words it is *a perfect differential*.

It is basically the statement, that a vector field has a potential iff its curl vanishes.

If you already know that $dz$ is an exact form, i.e a state function $z$ exists, then it is also closed $d(dz)=0$. Always and independently of the domain.

Note that on a non-simpy-connected domain the above condition is **not** sufficient for exactness. For example

$$ \omega = \frac{xdy - ydx}{x^2+y^2} $$ is closed but not exact which you may check immediately by integrating it along a circle around the origin.